# Web application framework with user management

Tags: web-apps, framework, web-services, user-management

I'm developing a brand new web application and I'm looking for a server-side framework that comes with some standard functionalities that I don't want to reinvent:

- user management
- user authentication, including with OpenID
- user registration
- password recovery

It would be great if I could also implement REST web services inside this web application. I'd consume them both from the web application itself (mostly via Ajax) and from mobile apps.

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, it is PHP, right? Any language is possible, PHP is the de facto standard, but Node.js is the rising start.

Comment: @Mawg Thanks, I usually work with Java, but any language is welcome

Comment: If you are familiar with python, I'd suggest django. It comes with a REST framework (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used **Spring Framework**, which comes with many modules that are useful for my requirements:

- Spring Security
- Spring Data JPA
- Spring Data REST
- ...

However I needed to build a lot of pieces on my own, regarding user management, but Spring documentation and community seem very rich.

Comment: Hi Bluish, were you able to eventually satisfy your requirements using spring? I am looking towards building a similar application.

Comment: @OmarAsifShaikh Hello, I levereged Spring for a lot of things, expecially for exposing my data with a REST repository (with Spring Data REST, which is easy) and securing them (with Spring Security). Anyway I haven't finished my development and moreover I'm still learning Spring. I'm not sorry for my choice ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying @bluish! Ill go ahead with spring as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can be of some assistance here.

Coldfusion has CFOath for your one pass needs:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/social-integration.html

If you need native login components cflogin has the parts you are looking for:

http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_j-l_07.html

Here is what comes out of the box: http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_j-l_07.html

For password recovery you will have to create something (and I would recommend doing this for native logins to as you want to have features like email notifications to the registered users that their password was changed, and some flow control.

Fortunately for you, Coldfusion is emensly easy to grasp.  If you can do HTML then Coldfusion should look very familiar.

Coldfusion costs $$$ but also lucky for you there is a very fast very powerful open source version called Railo.  It supports the same functionality with very little caveats: http://www.getrailo.org/

You can play with Railo express and run it on a pen drive.  http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/download/

I use it frequently when I need to prototype stuff or just play around and make things.

If you do consider going this route. There are lots of useful site like this one: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/ and this one http://www.bennadel.com/

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion is nice. I *like* ColdFusion, but Lavarel is the new kid on the block and overtaking ColdFusion.

[Building a User Management System in Laravel](https://gist.github.com/anchetaWern/4223764) explains what you need to know. And [this page](http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) of the official documentation say

> Laravel makes implementing authentication very simple. In fact, almost
>   everything is configured for you out of the box. The authentication
>   configuration file is located at config/auth.php, which contains
>   several well documented options for tweaking the behavior of the
>   authentication services.